# Как логировать конкретные запросы в PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, логирование, config

В конфигах есть параметр log_statement, который принимает четыре типа значений. Но что если я хочу логировать, например, только DELETE и SELECT? Есть ли возможность через саму конфигу или при помощи дополнительных внешних инструментов записывать в лог конкретные запросы?